# Canvas image toDataURL in hidden input not working on the click of submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to put the value of canvas pad in a Hidden input field when the user clicks the submit button. On the  click of the submit button, the value does not go to the hidden input. Here is what I have on my web page

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#myBtn1').click(function (event) {
    
                     var canvas = document.querySelector('#colors_sketch');
                   
                    var pad = new SignaturePad(canvas);
                    var data = pad.toDataURL();
                  
                    $('#savetarget').attr('src', data);
                    $('#SignatureDataUrl').val(data);
                    pad.off();
       });
            });
        </script>
```

```html
 <canvas id="colors_sketch" width="500" height="200" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;"></canvas>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="SignatureDataUrl">
    <input style="float: right; margin-bottom:20px" type="submit" id="myBtn1" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"  />
```

This is the rendered HTML for SignatureDataUrl

```
<input type="hidden" id="SignatureDataUrl" name="SignatureDataUrl" value="">
```

when I click the submit button, I don't see any value in SignatureDataUrl. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

Have you got the last version of this library? I saw that there was an open issue (fixed 4 months ago) about empty data returned from `toDataUrl()` method. Try to specify the type like this: `.toDataUrl("image/png")`

Also, try to create the `SignaturePad` object outside the click listener, in the `document.ready()` callback:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var canvas = document.querySelector('#colors_sketch');   
            var pad = new SignaturePad(canvas);
            
            $('#myBtn1').click(function (event) {
                var data = pad.toDataURL();
              
                $('#savetarget').attr('src', data);
                $('#SignatureDataUrl').val(data);
                pad.off();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**:

`asp-for` is an ASP.NET Tag Helper that will add `id` and `name` attributes to your HTML tag, but it works only server-side.

If you see `asp-for` in your rendered HTML, this means that id and name were not generated. That's why the jQuery selector won't work.

Try to add `id="SignatureDataUrl"` to your hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" id="SignatureDataUrl">
```

Comment: when I look at the rendered HTMl on web page. I see this: <input type="hidden" id="SignatureDataUrl" name="SignatureDataUrl" value="">. I also modified my original post to show the rendered HTML

Comment: SignatureDataURl is still null when i click the submit button. This is what I have on my page: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: In the click listener, call `signaturePad.isEmpty()` method. If it is true, it means that there's something wrong with the SignaturePad linking to canvas. Otherwise, the issue is linked to `toDataUrl()`.

Comment: should I call var test = signaturePad.isEmpty();

Comment: I am not very familiar with jquery so tried this code and alert is empty.   var canvas = document.getElementById("colors_sketch");
                alert(canvas);
                var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                alert(datURL);
               document.getElementById("SignatureDataUrl").src = dataURL;

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this in this [link](https://codepen.io/icreate/pen/eYLxBjO)

```
// correction
<input type="hidden" id='SignatureDataUrl' asp-for="SignatureDataUrl">
```

The issue was, you are accessing an id='SignatureDataUrl' but it wasn't defined